# How can I efficiently obtain every entry from a website with a return limit?

Tags: python, json, request

I am interested in parsing all of the entries from the federal job site: https://www.usajobs.gov/ for data analysis.

I have read through the API and in this section: https://developer.usajobs.gov/Guides/Rate-Limiting, it says the following:

> Maximum of 5,000 job records per query* (I am actually getting 10,000 job records in my output)
>
> Maximum of 500 job records returned per request

Here is the rest of the API reference: https://developer.usajobs.gov/API-Reference

---

So here is my question:

How can I go to the next 10,000 until all records are found?

What I am doing:

```
response = requests.get('https://data.usajobs.gov/api/Search?Page=20&ResultsPerPage=500', headers=headers)
```

Gives me 500 results per page in the form of a .json in which I dump them all into one .json until the 20th page by an increment page loop which ends up being all 10,000. I'm not sure what to do to get the next 10,000 until all entries are found.

Another idea is that I can do a query for each state but the downside is that I will lose everything outside of the U.S.

If someone can point me in the right direction for a better, simpler, and more efficient way to get all the entries than my proposed ideas, I would appreciate that too.

Comment: It seems like the particular request you wrote just gives page 20, correct? What's stopping you from putting "...Page=21&..."?

Comment: Hi Eric, so page 1 gives 500 results back which I append it to a file, page 2 gives another 500, all the way to page 20. That's all 10,000 results. Trying page 21 gives no results back. I know for sure there's more than 10,000 results but it only returns back 10,000 results divided in 500 results increments.

Answer (score 1):

The server likely gives some error when it can't find more pages. Try something like

"...?Page=25000&..."

just to see what it gives, then use a while loop with a manually managed incrementer instead of a for loop. The stopping condition for the while loop is to check if the server returns the error page.